# Selenium Webdriver failing to click. Unsure why

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code;

```
if united_states_hidden is not None:
    print("Country removed successfully")
time.sleep(10)
print("type(united_states_hidden) = ")
print(type(united_states_hidden))
print("united_states_hidden.text = " + united_states_hidden.text)
print("united_states_hidden.id = " + united_states_hidden.id)
print(united_states_hidden.is_displayed())
print(united_states_hidden.is_enabled())
united_states_hidden.click()
```

The outputs to the console are as follows:

```
Country removed successfully
type(united_states_hidden) = 
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
united_states_hidden.text = United States
united_states_hidden.id = ccea7858-6a0b-4aa8-afd5-72f75636fa44
True
True
```

As far as I am aware this should work as it is a clickable web element, however, no click is delivered to the element. Any help would be appreciated as I can't seem to find anything anywhere else. The element I am attempting to click is within a selector box.

Comment: What kind of element is this?
When you say no click is delivered how do you know that?

Comment: maybe this element is not listening to the click event. try the outer or inner element and see if anything's change?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a valid `WebElement` given you can print all of the info. like you did in your example.

It's possible the element located is not the element that is meant to be clicked, so perhaps the click is succeeding, but not really clicking anything.

You could try using a Javascript click and see if that helps:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", united_states_hidden)
```

If this does not work for you, we may need to see the HTML on the page and the locator strategy you are using to find `united_states_hidden` so that we can proceed.

Comment: If you are downvoting this answer, please leave a comment and let me know how this can be improved. Javascript click is a legitimate solution that has worked for me countless times in the past, and that is why I post it here.

Comment: Yeah, this was one of the first things I tried and it didn't work. I have figured out another way around the problem, but I am still interested as to why this issue occurred as no error message was delivered, etc. I'm not sure what the element is called but it is one of the options in a double selector box with both where you click an option on either side and then there are arrows to move it to/from the selected box.

Comment: Can you share how you found your way around the problem? It’s hard to visualize what the issue truly could be here without any of the page HTML for context. My best guess — given you have located a valid web element but clicks are not getting delivered where you expect them to — the web element that you have located might not be the correct one. Usually when this happens to me, there are two almost identical elements on the page, and Selenium is locating the wrong one for me, which produces unexpected behavior such as this scenario.

Comment: Sorry for the uber late reply but I did not manage to find a workaround, I had to pull data from a different page instead.